# About BJT, JFET & MOSFET transconductance

Tags: mosfet, bjt, jfet, transconductance

For BJT, the term "gm" refers to base-emitter conductance. But when we are talking about FETs and MOSFETs, where is this "gm"? Between gate-source junction for JFET? Drain to source conductance for MOSFET?

And what "gmb" means when talking about MOSFETs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general \$g_m\$ in simple term is a "gain" for any transconductance amplifier. And because transconductance amplifier is nothing more then a voltage controlled current source (VCCS) the gain expression is \$g_m = \frac{I_{out}}{V_{in}}\$.

For example if is \$g_m = 1\:Siemens\$ any change in the input voltage by \$1V\$ will change the output current by \$1A\$ (1 Ampere per Volt).

For BJT the transistor \$I_C\$ current is a controlled via input\$V_{BE}\$ voltage.

So, you plot \$I_C\$ vs \$V_{BE}\$

[image]

The \$g_m\$ is the slope of this curve

In MOSFET & JFET we have the same situation.

The output current \$I_D\$ is controlled via \$V_{GS}\$ voltage.

[image]

Hence again the slope of a \$I_D = f(V_{GS})\$ is a \$g_m =\frac{dI_D}{dV_{GS}} \$

The MOSFET in general is a 4 terminal device. The Gathe, Soure, Drain and the Body. And we can control the \$ I_D \$ via the gate terminal or via the Body. And this is why you have \$ g_{mb} \$

Comment: Nice. From the first picture; the small vgs represents input AC (actually triangular) and Vgs represents DC biased quiescent point, right?

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Comment: So, input AC voltage vgs changes DC biased Vgs just a little bit (if we are looking onto the slope)? Even if vgs is ten times higher/bigger than Vgs, Vgs changes just a little bit with input signal?

Comment: If Vin is lower then Vt the MOSFET is OFF and if Vin>> Vgs at DC. The MOSFET is in saturation. Hence  $$V_{INmin} = V_T$$ and $$V_{INmax}= V_T+ \frac{-1+\sqrt{1 + 2KR_DV_{DD}}}{K*R_D}$$ In real life the range is even smaller.

Comment: But if DC Vgs is biased above Vt, Vin does not need to be necessary above Vt.

Comment: What ? Are you sure?

Comment: Vt is a MOSFET threshold voltage Vgs(th) in datasheet.

Comment: If no DC is applied to the base of BJT and only AC is connected to base then transistor starts to conduct when AC exceeds 0,7V - class B amplifier; crossover distortion. But if the base is already biased by DC voltage then AC voltage doesn't have to reach at least 0,7V for the base to conduct - the transistor should amplify whole AC amplitude - it also depends how DC quiescent point is biased on the load line. That should be it if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes. Vgs(th) is value of Vgs needed for MOSFET to conduct. But that Vgs is usually already biased by DC voltage so AC can go through transistor amplification process without clipping the output signal. That must be it. right?

Comment: @Keno You're right, but too large and too small Vin will cause clipping.

Comment: I still don't understand how for example 5 Vp (AC) doesn't destroy the base-emitter junction... If I connect Vin of 5 Vp, Vgs changes only between/for few milivolts (while DC 0,7 V is applied to the base of BJT)?

Comment: With or without coupling capacitor? Without the coupling capacitor you can damage the BJT (except the emitter follower) is source impedance is low enough. With the coupling capacitor it will depend on a given situation. So, it is hard to say something in general term. But on the other hand if you want amplify a 5Vp signal your supply voltage need to be much larger then 5V. Also keep in mind that every amplifier will have a voltage gain (Av). Hence any Vin larger than Vcc/Av will cause clipping in amplifier.

Comment: I know about supply voltage, output characteristic, load line, active mode and others. But I still don't get it how 5 Vp doesn't destroy the base-emitter junction (lets say CE, with coupling caps). If coupling capacitors are added (while DC bias voltage is applied to whole transistor), then amplification process continuous normally? And if coupling capacitors aren't added (while DC bias voltage is applied to whole transistor), then the transistor gets destroyed due to base-emitter junction breakdown?

Comment: Not normally, the clipping will occur and the output signal will not look as a input signal anymore (distorted output voltage ).  And if this signal will be applied for a long time, the DC operating point will be shift to the new value. So you no longer have a amplifier. The voltage at the base will look something like this http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Negative-clamper.jpg and if Vin peak to peak value is greater than Veb breakdown voltage (typical >5V) you can even damage the BJT.

Comment: Last question: If coupling capacitors are added and DC bias point is at the right place, then only 0.7 Vp can be generated at the input? If Vin is higher than 0.7 Vp, than the BJT gets damaged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58149/discussion-between-keno-and-g36).

Answer (score 1):

In the bjt ic=gm*vbe refers to base-emitter conductance.

Similarly, in field effect transistors, and MOSFETs in particular, refers to gate-source conductance.Transconductance is the change in the drain current when we have small change in the gate/source voltage.id = gm*vgs

gmb: refers to  transconductance  which appears when we have the body effect.This occurs when VBS<>0(Voltage in the Bulk and Voltage in the source).

Notice:The terminal of bulk should usually be connected to the lowest potential of the circuit(ground or -VSS).This gmb provides a second current in the circuit with value ib=gmb*vbs

[image]

If body effect appears in your circuit your small signal model is the above

Comment: But if bulk is connected to source, body effect cannot occur, right? Because if bulk and source are connected together there is no voltage difference, so no Vbs, right?

Comment: All you refer is right

Comment: But bulk is always connected to source, right? Or not?

Comment: The terminal of bulk should usually be connected to the lowest potential of the circuit(ground or -VSS).In the most CMOS process bulk shouldn't connect in the source