How to derive voltage gain in Common Emitter (CE) NPN BJT configuration?
Looking at Microelectronic Circuits - Sedra & Smith,
I understand how to determine eq (7.9), and I know eq(7.12),
can someone share a step by step derivation to determine eq(7.20)? Thanks!
Attached are eq pics.




Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356746/why-is-transconductance-defined-so/356770#356770

derivation
Assuming their simplified model for the collector current and a grounded emitter case, I'll get directly to your question and derive \$A_v\$ from the large-scale equations:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{C}}&=I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\tag{7.12}
\\\\
V_{_\text{CE}}&=V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{C}}
\\\\
V_{_\text{CE}}&=V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\tag{7.9}
\\\\
&\text{then,}
\\\\
\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}&=\text{d}\left[V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\right]
\\\\
\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}&=\text{d} V_{_\text{CC}}-\text{d}\left[R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\right]
\\\\
\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}&=0-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\text{d}\left[\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\right]
\\\\
\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}&=-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\frac{\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}}{\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}}&=-R_{_\text{C}}\left[I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\right]\frac{1}{V_T}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}}{\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}}&=-R_{_\text{C}}\,I_{_\text{C}}\frac{1}{V_T}
\\\\
A_v&=\frac{\text{d} V_{_\text{CE}}}{\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}}=-\left(\frac{I_{_\text{C}}}{V_T}\right)R_{_\text{C}}\tag{7.20}
\end{align*}$$
notes
In reality, input signals are not infinitesimally small, but are of course finite. Also, since the collector current must vary significantly to cause any meaninful voltage change at the output, it's pretty obvious that \$A_v\$, which depends upon \$I_{_\text{C}}\$, must vary with the applied input signal. And this necessarily causes output distortion. Various methods are used to deal with this, including both local and global negative feedbacks.
Keep a firm grip on that idea as you continue reading. The above is only accurate for a specific operating point and for infinitely small signals.
G36 takes you to a good answer for you. But you didn't provide your context from Sedra & Smith. And it matters. Both the textbook and also the answer by jonk are discussing a grounded-emitter (jonk)/grounded-source (book) context, which is the maximum voltage gain situation. (This also means that \$V_{_\text{CE}}=V_{_\text{C}}\$.)
Such stages are almost never used in isolation because the voltage gain itself varies quite strongly with the applied signal, \$v_{_\text{BE}}\$, causing significant distortion. So these particular grounded-emitter stages are almost always used within a larger circuit structure that includes global negative feedback (NFB) to help linearize the behavior and remove the distortion caused by a widely varying gain. Only in the case where \$v_{_\text{BE}}=\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}\$ (read as: an infinitely small change around the \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ bias point) is the output actually linear. Then and only then is \$\text{d}V_{_\text{CE}}=A_v\cdot\text{d}V_{_\text{BE}}\$ or \$A_v=\frac{\text{d}\,V_{_\text{CE}}}{\text{d}\,V_{_\text{BE}}}\$.
The textbook applies \$I_{_\text{C}}=I_{_\text{SAT}}\,\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\right)\$. This is a simplification and is a very good approximation. But it isn't Shockley's equation -- note that if \$V_{_\text{BE}}=0\:\text{V}\$ that equation would suggest some small, non-zero collector current. Shockley's equation includes an obvious correction to repair that problem. (See equation \$\ref{eq1}\$ below and note the -1 term in the 3rd factor there.)
The Early Effect also alters this behavior enough to be a problem.
The equation they give really only applies to common small-signal bipolars. High power bipolars have emission coefficients that significantly modify the behavior, as well.
Using a binomial expansion, a fuller large-scale DC equation would be:
$$I_{_\text{C}}=I_{_\text{SAT}}\left[1-\frac{V_{_\text{BC}}}{V_A}\right]\,\left[\exp\left(\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{\eta\, V_T}\right)-1\right]\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
where \$1-\frac{V_{_\text{BC}}}{V_A}\$ represents the Early Effect and \$\eta\$ is the emission coefficient.
Temperature significantly impacts \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$ and, obviously, \$V_T\$. The sign of the change in \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$ is opposite to the sign of the change in \$V_T\$, with respect to temperature changes. And the magnitude of the change in \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$ is very much larger than the magnitude of the change in \$V_T\$, so the temperature changes in \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$ dominate the over-all bipolar's collector current response to temperature.
And there are still more modifications to take into account for changes in behavior at low currents and at high currents. This means any given bipolar only behaves simply over a range of somewhere roughly between 3 and 5 orders of collector current magnitude. So keep these notes in the back of your mind.
deeper delve for a moment
To better understand \$I_{_\text{SAT}}\$ and \$\eta\$ I'm adding this chart, with modifications by me, taken from Ian Getreu's "Modeling the Bipolar Transistor" text:

The x-axis may not be immediately obvious, unless you realize that \$V_T=\frac{k\,T}{q}\$. Then you can see that the x-axis is just \$\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}}{V_T}\$.
It's a bit much to take in, all at once. But if you spend a little time on it a great deal will become clearer. For example, when I earlier mentioned the 3-5 orders of magnitude range for the collector current, I was talking about the area in the green-colored box where the base current and the collector current are parallel to each other. The ratio of the collector current to the base current is relatively fixed in this box, which is why the idea of \$\beta\$ (or \$h_{_\text{FE}}\$) has good purchase in design work.
But when the collector currents get too low then the formation of emitter-base surface channels, the recombination of surface carriers, and the recombination of carriers in the emitter-base space-charge layer create a new behavior. And when the collector currents gets too high then the injection of minority carriers into the base region become increasingly important (in comparison against the majority carrier concentrations) because the space-charge neutrality must be maintained in the base and this means that the majority concentration has to increase by the same amount. Also, in high current regimes the bulk resistance present at the base, emitter, and collector show themselves, as well.
The slope showing in the diagram for the design-range of the bipolar will show a slope of 1 (emission coefficient of \$\eta=1\$) for small signal bipolars. But for specialized transistors (high power, for example), you can expect that \$\eta\gt1\$. This may be something you need to account for when using high-power bipolars.
It's not necessary to dig into all this for most purposes. Usually, you find a transistor that operates in the design range for the bipolar and you do not look for bipolars that will be forced to operate at the low-end or high-end of their behaviors. Those outside-the-norm areas are rarely used and you need experience there to know better what you are doing, then. So don't worry about it, for now.
final note
I know I'm being pedantic. But if you become careless in your view, then you will find unexpected difficulties arising later, forcing you to root out false assumptions at some later date. Better to avoid letting them take deeper root in the first place.
We tend to simplify things (ignore effects that aren't dominant) so that we can think more easily. But reality is often quite a bit more complicated. Just keep in mind that for most applications, the simplified model works very well. But also remember that it only works within a certain area of operation. Spice programs are designed to use very complex models that cover a much wider range of behavior. But if you are doing your job well, and selecting bipolar parts that are designed for the range of operation you need, then you can use the simpler models.

@ periblepsis, no, I dont think you are "pedantic". Your explanations have exactly the level of detail that is appropriate to understand the function of the transistor, controlled by Vbe. This is especially true for the necessity of negative feedback.
A small addition to your explanation (case VBE=0): Shockley's equation is also correct for this case, because the characteristic curve Ic=f(Vce) for VBE=0 does not pass through the origin, but there is a small (negative) current.

@LvW I was noting the textbook didn't use the Shockley equation, but a simplification that doesn't work in the extreme. The saturation current is the y-axis intercept for the few useful orders of magnitude over which the bipolar is designed. There are several y-axis intercepts used to cover low-current and high-current regimes.) So I'm aware. I just felt that adding an explanation about the -1 term would require charts. And I didn't want to haul that in. Thanks for the kind word about having the right level of detail. Coming from you that means a lot. :)

@LvW I've added some additional material that I hope won't overwhelm the questioner, but which may address more of what you were discussing in your comment. Best wishes and much thanks for being here. I appreciate your presence very much. :)

@ priblepsis Regarding your last edit: The significance and importance of the last section of your “final note” cannot be overestimated because your statements apply to all areas of electronics in general. In order to develop an understanding of how components and circuits work, it is in my opinion very important to initially neglect all secondary effects, but to be aware of this simplification and to know its scope of validity.

@ periblepsis For example, the question of BJT small-signal models in conjunction (and comparison) with the BJTs physical working principle has often been discussed here in this forum, but we should always bear in mind that the BJT model with a current-controlled current source is only a model that can be used for calculations - but it does not illustrate the actual physical functioning of the BJT.

@LvW Thanks for your added discussion. I can't thank you enough for the profound additions and how that helped me add a few more helpful details. I hope the results of our joint thoughts help others when reading through what's been presented. You have my profound respect (and appreciation.) Best wishes. And my thanks for taking your time to share your own mind with me on this. It's my pleasure and honor that you took a moment here for me.
