# Transconductance of a device

Tags: mosfet, bjt, gain, transconductance

I would like to know what does it mean when someone says "*that the transconductance of a FET or MOSFET is less compared to that of a bipolar junction transistor (BJT)*".

I even heard someone saying that "*This particular JFET has lots of transconductance (about 25mS at its Idss of 6-12mA)*" What does this mean? And how does he know this? Is it given in the datasheet of every single JFET? 
There is something related to transconductance in a datasheet which is the following:

[image]

I know that the **Idss** is the maximum current that a JFET can handle.

I also know that the transconductance of a device is useful to calculate the gain of a device, unless we use emitter degeneration.

For a BJT the transconductance is: \$g_m = \frac{I_c}{V_t}\$ where (\$V_t\$ is thermal voltage)

For a JFET the transconductance is: \$g_m = \frac{I_d}{V_{gs}}\$

Comment: Please provide a link to the DS that you got the graph from.

Comment: Something extra should be added to that sentence for it to be true: "that the transconductance of a FET or MOSFET is less compared to that of a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) **at the same biasing current**" Without saying that the biasing current (Ic, Id etc) is the same the statement is not true.

Comment: Here's the datasheet where I got this graph:http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MMBFU310LT1-D.PDF

Comment: Also you should look up what transconductance (gm) actually is and how it relates to a DC transfer curve. You mention Idss which isn't relevant, even with emitter degeneration gm **is** still relevant. How relevant depends on the value of the emitter deg. resistor and the value of gm. I think you still have some studying to do to fully see the relations between these parameters. Next time you "hear something" **ask for an explanation** from that person. Remembering statements without understanding them is pointless and not the way to learn electronics.

Comment: gm is a slope of Iout = f(Vin). For a FET's it is Id = f(Vgs). And for BJT's Ic = f(Vbe). And the steeper slope is the "better" amplifier we can build (more gain for a smaller change in the input).  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302832/about-bjt-jfet-mosfet-transconductance/302848#302848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transconductance tells you how much the current changes when you increase/decrease the gate/base a very *tiny* bit. It is a *small-signal* parameter. So a \$g_m = 25mS\$ at a \$v_{GS} = 0V, v_{DS} = 10V\$ like in your graph will mean that if you increase \$v_{GS}\$ a *very tiny bit* by \$\Delta v_{GS}\$, that the drain current will also increase a bit by \$\Delta i_d \approx 25mS \cdot \Delta v_{GS}\$.

For BJT's, the transconductance gain can be approximated by

$$g_m \approx \frac{I_c}{n V_T}$$

With \$n\$ the emission coefficient, \$V_T\$ the thermal voltage.

This means that the transconductance is proportional to \$I_c\$, or

$$g_m \sim I_c$$

For MOSFET's (similar to JFET's) the situation is a bit different. The approximation of the transconductance gain is here:

$$g_m \approx \frac{2 I_d}{V_{GS} - V_{TH}}$$

In order to make \$g_m\$ go up, we can just decrease \$V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$, **however**: the current \$I_d\$ will *also* decrease when doing that. It turns out that this decrease is approximately:

$$I_d \sim (V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2$$

So you can write that the transconductance is proportional to

$$g_m \sim \sqrt{I_d}$$

or

$$g_m \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{V_{GS}-V_{TH}}}$$

And this is a bit annoying. This dependency is much slower! So in order to get the same \$g_m\$ for a FET, you will need a **lot** of current (limited by power consumption and velocity saturation, where the formula doesn't apply anymore), or almost **no** \$V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$ voltage (where \$I_d\$ will usually reach impractically low levels \$\sim nA\$). There *is* one way of solving this, and that is making the FET gigantic, but that is usually impractical as well and it makes other parasitic effects worse.